# Trim trailing spaces before newlines in a single multi-line string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have this single string, here I denote spaces (" ") with ^

```
^^quick^^^\n
^brown^^^\n
^^fox^^^^^\n
```

What regular expression to use to remove trailing spaces with .replace()?
using `replace(/\s+$/g, "")` not really helpful since that only removes the spaces 
on the last line with "fox".

Going through other questions I found that `replace(/\s+(?:$|\n)/g,"")` matches the right sections
but also gets rid of the new line characters but I do need them.

So the perfect result will be:

```
^^quick\n
^brown\n
^^fox\n
```

(only trailing spaces are removed everything else stays)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the `'m'` multi-line modifier.

```
replace(/\s+$/gm, "")
```

Or faster still...

```
replace(/\s\s*$/gm, "")
```

Why is this faster? See: [Faster JavaScript Trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript)

**Addendum:** The above expression has the potentially unwanted effect of compressing adjacent newlines. If this is not the desired behavior then the following pattern is preferred:

```
replace(/[^\S\r\n]+$/gm, "")
```

**Edited 2013-11-17:** - Added alternative pattern which does not compress consecutive newlines. (Thanks to dalgard for pointing this deficiency out.)

Comment: Seems to have the unwanted side-effect of reducing multiple line-breaks to one?

Comment: @dalgard - You are correct. The answer is now updated with an alternative pattern which does not have this adverse effect. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: What about if I would like to include leading spaces in `replace(/[^\S\r\n]+$/gm, "")` ?

Comment: @leonard vertighel - This one should do the trick: `replace(/^[^\S\r\n]+|[^\S\r\n]+$/gm, "")`