# How to trim whitespace before carriage return in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have an input of

```
123                 
123 567              
987

98765
```

I know that `.replace(/ /g, "").trim()` will remove all the white space and leave carriage returns, but I want to leave the whitespace that's in the middle of two character strings contained between 2 carriage returns as well.

Is that possible with regex?

Comment: str.replace(/\s+\n\s*/,"\n") ???

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568797/trim-trailing-spaces-before-newlines-in-a-single-multi-line-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to match the return with spaces and replace it. So look so whitespace before a return and replace it with just the return/

```js
var str = "hello world    \nChees Fries\n\nfoo";
console.log(str.replace(/\s+\n\s*/,"\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you split using `split("\n");` and then `trim()` each. Also skip out ones with 0 length. Insert the elements into new array and then `join("\n")`.